# Need help on inserting data to table with Foreign Key in MySQL using Node RestAPI

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest

I am new to Node.js and RestAPI, and I tried to do CRUD on Node.js, then I encounter this error:

"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_gis`.`banksampah`, CONSTRAINT `banksampah_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`WorkingAreaID`) REFERENCES `working_area` (`ID`))"

I have already checked whether the value that I inputted were available on the references field, any idea why this error happen? thanks in advance

Here is my model:

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import db from '../config/database.js';

const {DataTypes} = Sequelize;

const Marker = db.define('banksampah', {
  Name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  Address: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT
  },
  WorkingAreaID:{
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  Lat: {
    type: DataTypes.FLOAT
  },
  Long: {
    type: DataTypes.FLOAT
  },
}, {
 freezeTableName: true
});

export default Marker;
```

Here is the parse function:

```
export const createMarker = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Marker.create(req.body);
    res.json({
        "message":"Marker Created"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({message: error.message});
  } 
}
```

Here is the request:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/
Content-Content-Type: application/json

{
 "Name": "Bank Sampah Cikarang 1",
 "Address": "Cikarang Utara",
 "WorkingAreaID": 1,
 "Lat": 6.0,
 "Long": -106.0
}
```

and Here is the FK Reference table (working_area):

[image: Database Table]

Comment: The error message tells that before inserting the row with `"WorkingAreaID": 1,` you must insert a row into `working_area` table with `ID=1` value.

Comment: there is already a data with ID 1 in the working_area (the table screenshot is working_area table)

Comment: Please show the code where you parse the request body and insert the element ...

Comment: I already edit my question thanks